# How do I know the return value of a java method?

Tags: java

how do i know that what i have to return in one contractor whether it has argument or not?

```
public RaceTurtle(RaceWindow w, int i) {

        RaceWindow.getStartXPos(1);
        RaceWindow.getStartYPos(1);


    }

    public int getX() {
        return ;// how do i know what should i return here 


    }

    public void raceStep() {
        RaceWindow.getStartXPos(getX());


    }
}
```

Comment: The signature indicates that you should return Int.

Comment: You need to provide more information, as it stands the code you've provided does not make sense.

Comment: "How do I know what….?" -- the type of the return value is indicated by the declaration of the method: _int_ getX().  The appropriate value to return depends solely on what you want the method to do and how you want its callers to use it, neither of which are apparent in the given code fragment.

Comment: The things you do in constructur definitely must not belong there. The sense of the 'RaceTurtle' looks to be unclear. It looks like you try to solve your task in a sort of illegal way. Share the task itself then.

Comment: I don’t uderstand the question, but a couple of attempts nevertheless: (1) You decide yourself what to return. (2) You ask those that wish to call your method what it should return. (3) You create an attribute (instance variable) `x` and return its value. All guessing, though.

Answer (score 1):

By contractor, I assume you mean constructor.
This is your constructor:

```
 public RaceTurtle(RaceWindow w, int i) {

       RaceWindow.getStartXPos(1);
       RaceWindow.getStartYPos(1);
 }
```

.

.

.

THIS below is called a method, not a constructor or contractor:

```
 public int getX() {
        return ;// how do i know what should i return here 

    }
```

We know it should return an **int** because you said so in the **signature**.

Here's the method signature:

```
public int getX() {
```